# Only last CSS3 Sub-Menus completely accessible

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, submenu

I'm trying to get this CSS3 Menu to work with more than one sub-menu per item (see the url below)

Trying to access View -> Messages -> Messages or below is impossible.

How can it be fixed so I can keep going passed the first line of a sub-menu followed by another one?
The menu are probably all loaded but only the :hover-ed one is visible?

http://jsfiddle.net/wJDzY/1/

Thanks!

`

```
.menu,
.menu ul,
.menu li,
.menu a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

/* Menu */
.menu { 
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;

    background: #4c4e5a;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.menu li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
}

/* Links */

.menu li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 14px;
    margin: 6px 0;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-decoration: none;

    border-left: 1px solid #393942;
    border-right: 1px solid #4f5058;

    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;

    color: #f3f3f3;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.6);

    -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
}

.menu li:first-child a { border-left: none; }
.menu li:last-child a{ border-right: none; }

.menu li:hover > a { color: #8fde62; }

/* Sub Menu */

.menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;

    opacity: 0;
    background: #000;


    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;

    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
}

.menu li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; }

.menu ul li {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;

    -webkit-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    transition: height .25s ease .1s;
}

.menu li:hover > ul li {
    height: 36px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu ul li a {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 4px 0 4px 40px;
    margin: 0;

    border: none;

}

.menu ul li:last-child a { border: none; }

.menu ul ul{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 90%;

    opacity: 0;



    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;

    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
}

.menu ul ul:after { right: 100%; border: solid transparent; content: " "; height: 0; width: 0; position: absolute; pointer-events: none; } 

.menu ul ul:after { border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); border-right-color: #000; border-width: 8px; top: 20px; margin-top: -8px; }

/* Icons */

.menu a.documents { background: url(http://designmodo.com/demo/css3dropdownmenu/img/docs.png) no-repeat 6px center; }
.menu a.messages { background: url(http://designmodo.com/demo/css3dropdownmenu/img/bubble.png) no-repeat 6px center; }
.menu a.signout { background: url(http://designmodo.com/demo/css3dropdownmenu/img/arrow.png) no-repeat 6px center; }                                

<ul class="menu">

    <li><a href="#">My dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Likes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Views</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="documents">Documents</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="signout">Messages</a> <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="documents">Documents</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="messages">Messages</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="signout">Sign Out</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="signout">Views</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="documents">Documents</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="signout">Messages</a>
                     <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="documents">Documents</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="messages">Messages</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="signout">Sign Out</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="signout">Views</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="documents">Documents</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="messages">Messages</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="signout">Sign Out</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Uploads</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Documents</a></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not go to View -> Messages -> Messages, because you used opacity to hide and show ul. Element doesn't get disappear, It just hidden. So when you go to View -> Messages -> Messages the below element views > views > ul shows. If you will use display rather than opacity you will get right result.

I have changed opacity with display and hope this will help you. [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wJDzY/3/)

```
.menu ul {
display: none;
}
.menu li:hover > ul {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a whole lot, that fixed it! :)
I'm just starting with CSS, now I'll need to figure out why this menu is popping bellow my <article> in IE9 only...

Comment: If you find it useful, please mark answer as correct. Thanks :)

Comment: It will help me to unlock some feature, like comment on questions.

Comment: Oops, first question here, didn't notice I could do more than up/down vote (which I can't it seems until I reach 15 points :)
cheers!

Answer (score 0):

SEE UPDATED CODE
Here problem of second sublisting. So you need to add class and css to second li that is coming after 1st li. See my example i hope you can better undersand its working.

```
--------------CSS------------------
.SubMenu2 ul { display:none;}        
li.SubMenu2:hover > ul{ display:block; }    


-------------HTML------------------
    <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">My dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Likes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Views</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="documents">Documents</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="signout">Messages</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="documents">Messages1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="messages">Messages2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="signout">Messages3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="SubMenu2"><a href="#" class="signout">Views</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="documents">Viewsub1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="messages">Viewsub2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="signout">Viewsub3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Uploads</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Documents</a></li>
    </ul>  

    <li><a href="#">Uploads</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Documents</a></li>
```

Comment: As long as you only have one opening sub-menus, that'll work, the problem is when you have 2 on the same level and try to access any of them before the last one. :)